# Run 16-bit command line application on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, command-line, 64-bit, cmd, 16-bit

I have 16-bit command line tools that I want to run on Windows 7 x64

I don't want to use a Virtual Machine

Can the 16-bit tools be wrapped in some way?

Maybe a 16-bit CMD.exe emulator

Comment: A 16 bit CMD.exe emulator would be in fact a virtual machine. See DosBOX for example.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: With Virtual Machine I meant like in VMWare, you know, a whole OS, having to share folders and so on, but DosBOX sounds good. I'll try it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://takeda-toshiya.my.coocan.jp/msdos/

This may help you. (Japanese website)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried downloading XP Mode (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) for Windows 7?  I know it works for 16bit GUI applications, but I don't know about command line programs.

also, you might want to look at DosBox (http://www.dosbox.com).  It runs old DOS games, i don't know how it interacts with Windows, however, so I don't know if you can access the file system, etc from DosBox.

good luck,
Mark

Comment: I thought of that after I posted.  I don't there there's really no other way.

Comment: I use DosBox to do this sort of thing and I have generally been successful.  You are indeed able to share files and folders with dosbox, although long filenames or names with non-ASCII characters may not be handled as expected.  There is more information (as well as examples) in the DosBox documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You must use some kind of a virtual machine.   16-bit is just not supported on Win64.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are up to productivity apps.  Its a variant of Dosbox
but built for old business apps

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vdos/